# How to pull values from same table using values within the same table?

Tags: sql

I have a table that contains a description column and there are various other columns within the same table that contain integer values that reflect those descriptions.  In the application, I need to note the description using those values.

```
SC_CODE  SC_DESC            UT_CODE  SC_ALT_CODE  SC_CANX_CODE
1        BKG RESERVATION    1        4            901       
4        BKG CASH TRADE     1        NULL         904       
901      BKG RES CANCEL     1        NULL         NULL
```

Query needs to return:

```
SC_CODE  SC_DESC            UT_CODE  SC_DESC(SC_ALT_CODE) SC_DESC(SC_CANX_CODE)
1        BKG RESERVATION    1        BKG CASH TRADE       BKG RES CANCEL
```

I put SC_CODE row 4 in there just as a place keeper. Any ideas???

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of ways it can be done.

## 1. Simple Code

This is the simplest to understand.  Each of the columns where you have data from a different table is populated by a subquery.  That subquery executes once for each row in your result set, pulling back the "first" description value for which its SC_CODE matches the related column (SC_ALT_CODE or SC_CANX_CODE) from the main table.

```sql
Select a.SC_CODE
, a.SC_DESC
, a.UT_CODE
, (
    select top 1 SC_DESC 
    from TheTable b 
    where b.SC_CODE = a.SC_ALT_CODE
) [SC_DESC(SC_ALT_CODE)]
, (
    select top 1 SC_DESC 
    from TheTable b 
    where b.SC_CODE = a.SC_CANX_CODE
) [SC_DESC(SC_CANX_CODE)]
from TheTable a
where SC_CODE = 1
```

An important note; if there are multiple rows with the same SC_CODE (e.g. 2 rows with value 901), the above may return either value for column `[SC_DESC(SC_CANX_CODE)]`.  We can change this by adding an `order by` clause to the related subquery if that scenario exists & is a concern; i.e. thus guaranteeing the order those results would be returned in & thus which would be first.

## 2. Using Joins

Generally this is the better approach, though it requires a bit more understanding of SQL to use.

```sql
Select a.SC_CODE
, a.SC_DESC
, a.UT_CODE
, b.SC_DESC [SC_DESC(SC_ALT_CODE)]
, c.SC_DESC [SC_DESC(SC_CANX_CODE)]
from TheTable a
left outer join TheTable b
    on b.SC_CODE = a.SC_ALT_CODE
left outer join TheTable c
    on c.SC_CODE = a.SC_CANX_CODE
where a.SC_CODE = 1
```

## Note

The two SQL examples above are both valid, and will both give you what you've asked for.  Depending on circumstances one may perform better than the other; generally #2 will perform better, but that's not true not in all cases.

However, importantly the output of these two is not guaranteed to always be the same.  i.e. if you had two rows in your table which both had `SC_CODE` with value `901` you'd only get 1 row with #1, but 2 with #2.  This is because #1 only returns 1 result from each of the linked tables for each row from the main (`a`) table; whilst in #2 we get 1 result row for each combination of matches from the 3 (a, b, & c) tables.